# XSLT - Appending strings to variable and printing it in a different file

Tags: xml, function, xslt

I have **XML** like this:

```
<article>
   <title>Article 1 title</title>
   <text>Lorem ipsum...</text>
   <image>http://example.com/img_01.jpg</image>
</article>
<article>
   <title>Article 2 title</title>
   <text>Dolor sit amet...</text>
   <image>http://example.com/img_02.jpg</image>
</article>
```

I need to show just relative path to the image and I want the absolute path to be written in another file. Let's call it `img_to_download.html`.

Here's my idea how to do it. I have one global variable called `image_src_download` where I append one absolute path string during every iteration of for-each (using the function `f:download` and giving it a parameter `image_src`). Then when for-each is finished, I put content of variable `image_src_download` to a separate file `img_to_download.html`.

My **XSLT** looks like this:

```
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>

        <xsl:variable name="image_src"/> <!-- this is for a single entry-->
        <xsl:variable name="image_src_download"/> <!-- this should carry all sources to images -->

<!-- This function should append new string to the existing one in variable image_src_download -->
        <xsl:function name="f:download">
            <xsl:param name="newLink"/>
            <xsl:variable name="image_src_download">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($image_src_download, $newLink, '\n')"/>
            </xsl:variable>
        </xsl:function>

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
                    <title>All articles</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <xsl:for-each select="article">
                        <h1><xsl:value-of select="title"/></h1>
                        <p><xsl:value-of select="text"/></p>

                        <xsl:variable name="image_src">
                            <xsl:value-of select="image"/>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:variable name="image_src_rel">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring($image_src, 20)"/> <!-- Strips beggining of the absolute URL and leaves just relative path to the file -->
                        </xsl:variable>

                            <xsl:value-of select="f:download($image_src)"/> <!-- This should append absolute path string of the current article image to variable image_src_download -->
                            <p><img src="{$image_src_rel}" /></p>
                    </xsl:for-each>

                </body>
            </html>

            <!-- Generates new file where there are absolute paths to images on each line-->
            <xsl:result-document href="img_to_download.html" method="html">
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>IMG to download</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$image_src_download"/>
                    </body>
                </html>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:template>
```

My **desired output** are two files.
File `articles.html` that looks like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
      <title>All articles</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Article 1 title</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      <p><img src="img_01.jpg"/></p>

      <h1>Article 2 title</h1>
      <p>Dolor sit amet...</p>
      <p><img src="img_02.jpg"/></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

File `img_to_download.html` that looks like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
      <title>IMG to download</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>
        http://example.com/img_01.jpg<br/>
        http://example.com/img_02.jpg<br/>    
      </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please, do you have an idea how to make this work?

All best, Johnny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT, you can't change variables once they are initialized. Instead, process the XML nodes twice with different modes in order to generate different output for the *article* elements. Maybe something like the following is sufficient for your task:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>...</head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
    <xsl:result-document href="img_to_download.html" method="html">
      <html>
        <head>...</head>
        <body>
          <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="extern"/>
          </p>
        </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:result-document>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="article">
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="title"/></h1>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="text"/></p>
    <p><img src="{tokenize(image, '/')[last()]}"/></p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="article" mode="extern">
    <img src="{image}"/>
    <br/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" mode="#all"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is quite easy to do**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:result-document href="articles.html">
     <html>
       <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
          <title>All articles</title>
        </head>
        <body>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
     </xsl:result-document>

     <xsl:result-document href="img_to_download.html">
    <html>
       <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
          <title>IMG to download</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <p>
           <xsl:apply-templates mode="url"/>
          </p>
        </body>
    </html>
     </xsl:result-document>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="title/text()">
  <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text/text()">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="image">
  <xsl:variable name="vSrc" select=
   "replace(., 'http://((.+/)*)(.+)', '$3')"/>
  <p><img src="{$vSrc}"/></p>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(self::image)]/text()" mode="url"/>

 <xsl:template match="image/text()" mode="url">
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<html>
    <article>
        <title>Article 1 title</title>
        <text>Lorem ipsum...</text>
        <image>http://example.com/img_01.jpg</image>
    </article>
    <article>
        <title>Article 2 title</title>
        <text>Dolor sit amet...</text>
        <image>http://example.com/img_02.jpg</image>
    </article>
</html>
```

**the following two files are created in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin` :**

articles.html:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>All articles</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Article 1 title</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      <p><img src="img_01.jpg"></p>
      <h1>Article 2 title</h1>
      <p>Dolor sit amet...</p>
      <p><img src="img_02.jpg"></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

img_to_download.html:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>IMG to download</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>
         http://example.com/img_01.jpg<br>
         http://example.com/img_02.jpg<br></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

**And it can be seen that the files contain exactly the wanted results**.